# Class constructor parameters in TypeScript

Tags: typescript, class

I am surffing some coding styles about TypeScript.

When initiating an object from a class.
What are the Pros and cons between these two code styles in TypeScript?

```
class Class3 {
    // members
    private readonly m1: Class1;
    private readonly m2: Class2;

    constructor({
        _m1 = new Class1(),
        _m2 = new Class2()
    }:{_m1:Class1, _m2:Class2}){
        this.m1 = _m1;
        this.m2 = _m2;
    }

    public foo() {
        console.log("Hello World a");
    }

}


class Class3 {
    // members
    private readonly m1: Class1;
    private readonly m2: Class2;

    constructor() {
        this.m1 = new Class1();
        this.m2 = new Class2();
    }

    public foo() {
        console.log("Hello World b");
    }
}
```

Comment: One accepts parameters and thus allows dependency injection, the other doesn't.

Comment: In which world the first one even compile ? This is not correct typescript

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
class Robot {
  private readonly brain: Brain
  private readonly laserBeam: LaserBeam

  constructor({
    // destructuring and providing default values
    brain = new Brain(),
    laserBeam = new LaserBeam()
  }: {
    // type signature for constructor options
    brain: Brain
    laserBeam: LaserBeam
  }) {
    // attaching these members to this instance
    this.brain = brain
    this.laserBeam = laserBeam
  }

  async destroyHumanity() {
    await this.brain.think()
    await this.laserBeam.charge()
    await this.laserBeam.fire()
    console.log("Goodbye world!")
  }
}
```

This is a robust pattern that can be used for a lot of things.

It's unfortunate how verbose it is, there's so much repetition, but it's a good pattern otherwise.

Comment: Thanks for replying me. I know IoC and DI, but I am still confused why defining in this way implement the DI pattern.    constructor({ brain = new Brain(), laserBeam = new LaserBeam() }: {
    // type signature for constructor options
    brain: Brain
    laserBeam: LaserBeam
  })